# Adjusting Camera to top view

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, camera-calibration, glm-math

Been trying to adjust the viewmatrix to top view. Cant seem to get the camera to rotate down instead of looking straight

```
else if (keyboard_key == GLFW_KEY_2 && keyaction == GLFW_PRESS) {
        // set camera's view matrix
        planet_camera.setViewMatrix(glm::vec3(0.0f,20.0f,0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(-5.0f,-0.0f, 0.0f));
        render_scene();
    }
```

```
void Camera::setViewMatrix(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 lookAt, glm::vec3 up)
    {
        mPosition = position;
        mLookAt = lookAt;
        mUp = up;

        mViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(mPosition, mLookAt, mUp);
    }
```

Comment: I'd really recommend using some library or writing specific rotation functions instead of providing the matrix values by hand.

Comment: My bad. Forget the function

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to send the view matrix as a uniform after you make the change to its position? Also, I think you have your up-vector wrong. Try:

```cpp
glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
```

The up-vector is the global "up"

Comment: it did not work. I still need to roll the camera down to look at the object